# Program ignoring condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement

In my code, I'm trying to prevent circles from overlapping so I specified it as a condition on the distance between the centres of the circles but it seems to not work all the time

as you can see :

[image]

could it be some kind of numerical precision rounding problem ?

Here is the relevant code (I can post the whole code if needed):

```
const double win_size = 800;
const double L = 50e-9; //box size (m)
const double k = 1.38e-23; // Boltzmann constant = 1.38e-23 J/K
const double R = 1.6e-10*30;  //N2 radius = 1.6e-10 m 
const double m = 4.65e-26; //N2 mass = 4.65e-26 kg

struct parameters{
    double x;
    double y;
    double v_x;
    double v_y;
};

bool empty_space(double x, double y, struct parameters gas[], int N, int i){
    if (i == 0) return true;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        if (pow(x-gas[i].x,2) + pow(y-gas[i].y,2) <= 4*R*R){
            cout << gas[i].x << " " << gas[i].y << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void initialize(struct parameters gas[], int N, double T){    // Sets initial conditions (velocity depends on temperature)
    int tries = 0;
    double x, y;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if (tries == 10000){
            cout << "Couldn't fit " << N << " molecules in the box, aborting simulation... " << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        x = R + (L - 2*R)*rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = R + (L - 2*R)*rand()/RAND_MAX;
        if (empty_space(x,y,gas,N,i)){
            gas[i].x = x;
            gas[i].y = y;
        }
        else {
            i--;
            tries++;
        }
        gas[i].v_x = sqrt(2*k*T/m)*(1-2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);
        gas[i].v_y = (2*(rand()%2) - 1)*sqrt(2*k*T/m - pow(gas[i].v_x, 2));
    }
}

void draw(int window, struct parameters gas[], int N, int automatic){
    g2_pen(window,g2_ink(window,0.8,0.3,0.4));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        g2_circle(window,gas[i].x*win_size/L,gas[i].y*win_size/L,R*win_size/L);
    }
    g2_flush(window);
    usleep(10000);
    g2_pen(window,0);
    g2_filled_rectangle(window,0,0,win_size,win_size);
    if (!automatic) getchar();
}
```

Comment: You want to check that the distance is greater than the radius, not the diameter.

Comment: Off topic: Recommend modifying to return `bool` and returning false instead of `exit(1)` on failure. Exiting the program at that time could be harmful.

Comment: Harmful to what ? (I don't know much about programming, I just do numerical physics)

Comment: C++ is a terrible language to try and learn from scratch. It's like trying to learn to drive in a Lamborghini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first debugging step is to print the coordinates of the circles that have clashed somehow, then see what the "distance" function is returning for their centers. My guess it it's somehow a rounding problem but this seems to be what you need to do next.

Comment: Would it help to use "set precision" ?

Comment: If it was a rounding problem, then quite likely the circles would be just touching each other, barely intersecting at all.  These are intersecting quite visibly.

Comment: @GuyGreer I don't have a good explanation for why the intersection is so small though, and not 1/4 or 1/2 of the circles. Debugging is needed.